# Swift ошибка #selector

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Такая проблема есть приложение которое раньше запускалось на эмуляторе и норм работало, но с некоторого времени оно выдаёт ошибку во всех строках такого типа:

```
cell.schetValuta.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.syncPeriodSetClick(_:)) , for: .touchUpInside)
```

Ошибка возникает вот тут "#selector(self.syncPeriodSetClick(_:))" и пишет что-то типа "Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'setNapominanieClick' that is not exposed to Objective-C" и поскольку я в разработке под ios новичок для меня это загадка. Нужна помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```
@objc func syncPeriodSetClick(_ sender: Any){
         print("tap btn")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка означает что Objective-C не видит ваш метод syncPeriodSetClick. Скорее всего из-за того, что он приватный.

Чтобы решить эту проблему добавьте `@objc` перед декларацией вашего метода.